# A special chess board

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coloring

Consider a special $n\times n$ chess board such that each $1\times 1$ square is ether black or white.

We  know that every $1\times 1$ square has exactly one white adjacent square (two squares are adjacent, if they share exactly one side). For example the figure shows a possible coloring for $n=4$.

Example:

[image]

a) Prove that if $n$ is an odd number, then the coloring is not possible!

b) Prove that if $n$ is an even number, then the coloring is possible!

c) Find the number of white cells if $n$ is an even number!

These problems are really beautiful, try them!

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed a fun problem ... not too easy but not too difficult either!

Comment: This would be better on puzzling.se

Answer (score 3):

I've thought this problem for a few days, but I *can't* solve part (a).  To enable others to edit my answer (and to avoid [losing reputation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12133/290189)), I'm making this community wiki.

## A story-like introduction to the problem (optional)

If you want your kid to think about this problem, you may tell them this story.

Once upon a time, there's a kingdom with $n^2$ sites.  To protect the land, the King  has decided to build castles  (white squares □), so that each site □/■ is protected by a neighbouring castle .  (Each castle has to pair up with another one.  ↔ )

Being too lazy to draw something like this,
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
   &  & \unicode{x1f3f0} & \unicode{x1f3f0} &  &  \\ \hline
  \unicode{x1f3f0} &  &  &  &  & \unicode{x1f3f0} \\ \hline
  \unicode{x1f3f0} &  &  &  &  & \unicode{x1f3f0} \\ \hline
   &  & \unicode{x1f3f0} & \unicode{x1f3f0} &  &  \\ \hline
   &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
  \unicode{x1f3f0} & \unicode{x1f3f0} &  &  & \unicode{x1f3f0} & \unicode{x1f3f0} \\ \hline
\end{array}
I'll use matrices in the rest of this post, but you may imagine that they are castles  in your kingdom ♔.

## Construction of beautiful squares

I use $1$ to denote white squares, and $0$ to denote black squares.  The proof for part (b) will be *constructive* and inductive.

The base cases are either trivial or given.
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
n=2 & n=4
\end{array}

The inductive hypothesis are

- the possibility of such construction for even $n$
- on the outermost layer, the digits repeat in the pattern $1,1,0,0$
- the existence of $1$ at exactly two corners.
- We can add one more observation here: symmetry about the vertical axis.  I'm *not* going to prove this point since I *don't* know how.

The inductive step is to construct a square matrix with size $(n+4)^2$.  In other words, we want to expand our kingdom by $4$ rows and columns.  To do this, we focus on the outermost layer.
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & & & 0 \\ 1 & & & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\
n=2 & n=4
\end{array}
The second outermost layer consists of $0$ only, while each digit in the outermost layer is *opposite* to the digit that it faces.
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} &
\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 &   &   &   &   &   &   & 0 \\
  1 &   & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 &   & 1 \\
  1 &   & 0 &   &   & 0 &   & 1 \\
  0 &   & 1 &   &   & 1 &   & 0 \\
  0 &   & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 &   & 0 \\
  1 &   &   &   &   &   &   & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
n=2+4 & n=4+4
\end{array}

My proof that such construction satisfies the question is to divide the scenario into two types: side and corner.  Up to any rotational and reflectional symmetry, we have these three situations.

### Side

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & \text{outermost} \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \text{second outermost} \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 1 & \text{apply induction} \\
\dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & \text{hypothesis here}
\end{array}
\right]
$$

### Corner

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{|cc} \hline
  \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \\
  \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{|cc} \hline 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \\
\end{array} &
\begin{array}{|cc} \hline
  \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \\
  \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} &
  \begin{array}{|cc} \hline 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \\
\end{array} \\
\text{corner is 1} & \text{corner is 0}
\end{array}
$$
Observations:
 - From corner $1$'s, we get corner $1$'s.  This shows that we've exactly two corner $1$'s and two corner $0$'s in each square.
 - the pattern $1,1,0,0$ is preserved on the sides and at the corners on the outermost layer.

### Ideas for part (c)

In *my* construction, half of each even layer is a white square.  We have the recurrence sequence $w_{n+4}=w_n+2(n+3)$, where $w_n$ denotes and number of white squares in a $n \times n$ chess board.  The initial conditions are $w_0=0$ and $w_2=2$.

\begin{alignat}{2}
w_{4k}-w_0 & = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{2(4i+3)} \quad && \text{(sum of arithmetic progression)} \\
 & = \frac{2[4(k-1)+3]+2[4(0)+3]}{2} \cdot k \quad && \left(\frac{\text{first term + last term}}{2} \times \text{no. of terms}\right) \\ 
 & = (4k+2)k \\
 & = 2k(2k+1)
\end{alignat}

The calculations for $w_{4k+2}$ are similar, and we arrive at
$$\bbox[1px, border: 1px solid black]{w_{2n}=n(n+1)} \quad\forall\,n\in\Bbb{N}.$$

Comment: I too am interested in a solution for (a). Been stuck on it for several hours.

Comment: @mich I tried thinking the white squares as pieces in a jigsaw puzzle, and I made some deductions, but far from solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer for a):

Consider the $2\times 2$ squares from the bottom left corner to the top right corner. Since $n$ is odd, the top right $1\times 1$ square is not in either of the $2\times 2$ squares. Write an A into each square of the main diagonal (from the bottom left to the top right corner), and a B into each square of the adjacent diagonals.

The bottom left $1\times 1$ square’s adjacent white square is in the bottom left $2\times 2$ square in a B square. Hence the other A now has an adjacent white square. Therefore in the next $2\times 2$ square the bottom left A’s adjacent white square must be one of the Bs in that $2\times 2$ square. The othet A now has an adjacent white square. And so on... Untill we arrive to the top right $1\times 1$ square. We get that it can’t have an adjacent white square, because in that case the A under it would have two white adjacent squares.[image]

Comment: l finally understand your answer when it read it the third. I believe that it is better to index the $A$'s and $B$'s so that it's easier to follow.